# Reading JSONOBjects within JSONObjects using javascript/Angular

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs

```
{  
   "APPLICATION_DETAIL":[
    {  
         "Application1":"",
         "Application2":"",
         "status":{  
            "Application1":"Active",
            "Application2":"Inactive"
         },
         "modifiedBy":"a123453"
      },
      {  
         "Application1":"",
         "Application2":"W",
         "status":{  
            "Application1":"Inactive",
            "Application2":"Inactive"
         },
         "modifiedBy":"a123456"
      }  
   ]
}
```

In the above JSON object , i am trying to check if the status of both the applications are inactive and if yes i need to delete that object i am right now facing challenge to even read the status values also the status list is dynamic it can be one value or multiple values any help would be appreciated

Comment: How are you reading the object? Post your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a code snippet to find all inactive applications indexes:

```js
var applications = {  
   "APPLICATION_DETAIL":[
    {  
         "Application1":"",
         "Application2":"",
         "status":{  
            "Application1":"Active",
            "Application2":"Inactive"
         },
         "modifiedBy":"a123453"
      },
      {  
         "Application1":"",
         "Application2":"W",
         "status":{  
            "Application1":"Inactive",
            "Application2":"Inactive"
         },
         "modifiedBy":"a123456"
      }  
   ]
}

applications = applications.APPLICATION_DETAIL;
var applicationsNumber = applications.length;
var objectsToRemove = [];

for(var appIndex = 0; appIndex < applicationsNumber; appIndex++) {
 var application = applications[appIndex];
 var isActive = false;;
 
 var statuses = Object.keys(application.status);
 var statusesNumner = statuses.length;
 
 for(var statusIndex = 0; statusIndex < statusesNumner; statusIndex++) {
  if(application.status[statuses[statusIndex]] === 'Active') {
   isActive = true;
  }
 }
 
 if(!isActive) {
  objectsToRemove.unshift(appIndex);
 }
}

console.log(objectsToRemove);

var removeObjectsNumber = objectsToRemove;
for(var removeIndex = 0; removeIndex < removeObjectsNumber; removeIndex++) {
  applications = applications.splice(removeIndex, 1);
}

console.log(applications);
```

Comment: This is working but i am sorry i am novice for delete if i use it is making it blank and i tried splice it is removing everything

Comment: Thank you !:) can you suggest me some tips to improve or u can give me some contact refrence of yours

Comment: When i try this code as is it is working but when i integrate it with my angular code it is failing i am getting the error on key method being called on non object i have also placed my code with the http call in the js fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/jc6dbm7s/ can you take a look at it pls i am sorry to be troubling you

Answer (score 0):

First i will Print your **Application status**:

> Copy this code and run in your **browser console**

```
 var test ={  
         "APPLICATION_DETAIL":[
       {  
         "Application1":"",
         "Application2":"",
         "status":{  
            "Application1":"Active",
            "Application2":"Inactive"
         },
         "modifiedBy":"a123453"
      },
      {  
         "Application1":"",
         "Application2":"W",
         "status":{  
            "Application1":"Inactive",
            "Application2":"Inactive"
         },
         "modifiedBy":"a123456"
      }  
   ]
}
for(var i=0 ; i<test.APPLICATION_DETAIL.length ; i++){
  console.log(test.APPLICATION_DETAIL[i].status.Application1);
  console.log(test.APPLICATION_DETAIL[i].status.Application2);
}
```

Now you can put **if** condition in it and do your action

Comment: if you want any help in if statement let me know

Comment: but i cant use this line test.APPLICATION_DETAIL[i].status.Application1 as the application1 itself is dynamic and it may have multiple applications like the status object can contain as many as 6 status to as low as 1

Comment: so you have to find key of status object  using Object.keys